# Backup of Apps and GUI Settings

Tags: 12.04, package-management, backup, gui

Well, I got (I think) a pretty basic question.

I'm new in Ubuntu, and I'm wondering how do I backup all I've installed and my GUI settings and tweaks.

I'm not pretty much interested in backing up info *(as Ubuntu Official Backup seems to be oriented to)*, since I work everything in dropbox or google drive, but better in all the drivers, programs (or packages as it is called in ubuntu... *btw, It's difficult to get used to terms, programs in windows, apps in macos, packages in ubuntu... well*)

So, long question made short: I want to backup my nvidia driver, Appearence and Mouse and Display settings, and overall all I've installed in my machine such as Skype, Chrome, Synapse, etc etc etc.

Any help or guidance is welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Under your home directory, there you will see lots of hidden files and folders. You may see them with "ls -al" . Most of them are for your application settings. But as you did not specifically mention which application settings you want to backup, I offer you to backup them all. First, tar and gzip them and then you may send it to dropbox.

Comment: so you're saying that windows gui customization, and apps are all stored in "ls-al" hidden folder? Well, I haven't seen it. I tried Ctrl+H but it's not listed there.

Comment: No apps are not there, only the configurations. All of the application settings you use, including your GUI configurations are under your home directory. For example check out .gconf or .config or .local  They all have configurations. As I said before as you are looking for a general solution, it is to backup all. BTW "ls -all" is the command for you to see your hidden files.